# After adding a disk ubuntu wont start normally (sda<->sdb)

Tags: boot, grub2, hard-drive

In my notebook are 2 disks: mSata appears as sdb and SATA appears as sda. I did a fresh install on the mSATA (sdb) including GRUB. All is fine. But when I remove the SATA the mSATA becomes sda and Ubuntu boots but only only in some maintenance command lines. I tried it the other way around: Installed Ubuntu on mSATA as sda (no SATA connected), all is fine but when I add the SATA this gets the name sda and my mSATA is sdb now and I have the same trouble. I wonder that this is in UUID times still an issue and would be happy about a helpful hint. The SATA disk contains only data and I use it also in different machine. I use Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

What is in your fstab file?
You can check it using

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

(you can replace nano with gedit, or any other text editor)

Each line should start with UUID=xxxx and you shouldn't see any reference to /dev/sda or /dev/sdb

If you need to know the UUID, run this command to list them

```
blkid
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my (fresh Ubuntu 16.04) /etc/fstab does not contain any references to sda or sdb, only UUID is used.